# Google Analytics: Can I target utm_term in an Advanced Segment?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to track clickthroughs from emails using tracking URLs (eg crafted at [URL builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en&ref_topic=1032998)).  I'm planning out the various terms to ensure that I have max flexibility in future, and can accommodate, and track different versions of the email (some crude AB testing).

I have found that in the advanced segments panel:

- Campaign maps to utm_campaign,
- Source maps to utm_source,
- Ad Content maps to utm_content, and
- Medium maps to utm_medium

**Can I target utm_term?**

Is this likely to be useful, or am I overthinking this :)

Tx for your consideration

[image: looking for the utm_term]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

utm_term maps to 'keyword', as in the image above...

*(sorry, I wasn't sure that was the case when I asked, or if what I wanted was useful... it is!)*

Answer (score 1):

Yeah its very useful if you are using only Anlytics to track your traffic . If you are using any other powerful software than no need .

Comment: thanks @ashish, do you know which 'selector' maps to utm_term in the UI above? Also interested in your thoughts on 'other powerful software'.. tx!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best thing to do...

When sharing a link, posting it to Twitter, sharing on Facebook etc... just look at the link in the address bar of your browser. For example:

```
https://www.example.com/path/tourl?utm_term=.ldkasksa#.maFasasf
```

Look for the question mark, followed by "utm." It doesn't matter what comes afterwards. For example, `?utm_term=.meanlinglesscrap#.nobodyreallyneeds`.

Before you share you link, just delete all the useless stuff! In the above example, you can just share:

```
https://www.example.com/path/tourl
```

... and the link still works! But now you don't have this sneaky tracking, following code going from place to place.

Happy to be of assistance! ;)